# Issues in formulas in excel

Tags: excel, formula

In Microsoft excel Formulas involve the use of commas for separation of formula constitutes like (lookup_value, table_array, in lookups). This is the norm.
However mine is asking to input semicolons as separators (lookup_value;table_array; and so on)
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following by changing local regional settings in Windows:

Go to `Control Panel` -> `Region and Language`.
In the first tab click on `Additional settings` button. 
Look for List separator and change it to a comma(`,`)

Open and close Excel.